# Implementing sieve of eratosthenes and then getting highest prime factor

Tags: c++, math, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I am stuck on trying to get the sieve to work. When I debug it, it tells me that stuff like 9 and 15 still evaluate to true when they go through the sieve. What causes this? Also, am I using the vector properly to get the highest prime factor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    long long n = 13195;
        long long sqrtn = sqrt(n);

        bool* boolarray = new bool[n];

        for(long long i = 0; i<=boolarray[sqrtn]; i++) {
                boolarray[i] = true;
        }

        long long x = 0;

        for(long long i=2; i<=sqrtn; i++) {
                if(boolarray[i]) {
                        for(long long j=pow(i, 2)+x*i; j<=n; j=pow(i, 2)+(++x*i))

                                        boolarray[j] = false;
                }
        }

        std::vector<long> primefactors;

        for(long long i = 0; i<=sqrtn; i++)
        {
                if(boolarray[i] && n % boolarray[i] == 0)
                        primefactors.push_back(i);
        }

        int answer = primefactors.back();

        printf("Answer: %i\n", answer);

        _sleep(10000);

        delete[] boolarray;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (An then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: I recommend you to revise your sieve algorithm, you can find many examples online.

Comment: That's how I found out that the sieve wasn't working.

Comment: Also note that that is a terribly inefficient way to find the largest prime factor in general.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you be so kind as to tell me why?

Comment: Because sieving to `n` is `O(n*log log n)` work and requires `O(n)` space, but the largest prime factor is usually much smaller. If you completely factorise `n`, that's at most `O(sqrt(n))` work and requires only `O(log n)` space (if you forget smaller prime factors, `O((log n)²)` is an upper bound if you remember all prime factors). If the largest prime factor is relatively small, it's much less work.

Comment: Consider that boolarray is an array of bool, so its values are all either 0 or 1. So how often will for(long long i = 0; i<=boolarray[sqrtn]; i++) iterate? At most twice. What about n % boolarray[i] == 0 when boolarray[i] can only be 0 or 1? Added a down vote because that code is just so bad.

Answer (score 1):

The following is wrong:

```
                    for(long long j=pow(i, 2)+x*i; j<=n; j=pow(i, 2)+(++x*i))
```

Both the initial value and the update expression for `j` are incorrect. I leave it as an exercise to figure out what exactly is wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: Ok I'll just spend a few more hours racking my brain and I'll get back to you. I already knew that was wrong.

Comment: How is this too localized? What the hell? I just want some help.

Comment: @Tetramputechture it's not locked so someone can still help you through comments if they feel like it (and many people are helpful like that) but SO is not for general debugging help, it's for focused questions